# How to convert Kindle books into PDF format?

Tags: pdf

I'm new to digital books and I use the Kindle app for Windows to read the books I bought but I hate how I can't read the bottom paragraph of a book in the Kindle app in the centre of the monitor; I have to bend my neck down and it gets sore fast.  Problem is that I can't move the Kindle book page up or halfway as when I'm reading a PDF document; if you try to move the page in Kindle it skips to the next new page.  So, I thought maybe converting my books to PDF will solve the problem.

How do I convert Kindle books into the PDF format?

Does anyone have another solution? Perhaps a fancier reader that allows me to scroll Kindle book pages?

Windows 7 64-bit
IE 8

Comment: I'd imagine any sort of fix for this would be a hack as eBooks are designed for security and preventing people from just sharing them around: things that PDFs aren't.

Comment: @music2myear: E-books are designed to electronically store and display books. Some e-book formats (including PDF and AZW) come with DRM, but that's not the defining characteristic of ebooks. Typically, converting a file that has DRM protection, even to another format with DRM protection, requires removing the DRM first. If that's considered a "hack", then yes, doing this involves a hack. Though it's not a hack in the sense that it's a [kludgy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kludgy), hackish solution.

Comment: I stand corrected regarding the designed purpose for ebooks, Lese majeste. However, I would differ with your definition of a "hack".

Answer (score 5):

Try [calibre](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/01/how-to-strip-drm-from-kindle-e-books-and-others/)? I don't have a kindle, so I've never tried what you're asking for myself, YMMV.

Comment: Got Calibre but I don't think it converts Kindle into PDF.

Comment: @verve: [It does](http://www.ebook-converter.com/kindle-drm-removal.htm), but you need to remove the DRM on your AZW file using one of the linked to DRM-removal plugins or [a 3rd-party tool](http://www.ebook-converter.com/kindle-drm-removal.htm) first.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Is that tool free from viruses etcetera.  Also, can what you linked to just remove the DRM without converting to another format?  Will it damage the book and prevent it from being used in the Kindle for PC app?

Comment: @verve: I'm pretty sure it's clean. It [checks out on virscan.org](http://r.virscan.org/fd459f2932a01a2094286e958b90e99a), but if you want to verify it yourself, you can check it out using avast or one of the other AVs with an online file scanner. Alternatively, you could try [this Kindle DRM remover](http://roke-isle.blogspot.com/2010/05/unskindle-step-by-step-guide.html). This is the follow up to Unswindle, which was recommended by AfterDawn and Lifehacker, so it's also likely to be legit.

Comment: Are any of these apps free?  The first one is sneaky; people say it's just a demo.  Have you used any of them?

Answer (score 1):

The very hackish solution: resize the Kindle application window.

Comment: Cheeky chap. Hee.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am ware there are at least two pieces of software that you require to accommodate your needs and should be used in conjunction with reference to the two articles whose weblinks are provided:

The first is called [Briss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) which is a visual PDF Cropping Tool.

The second is called [K2PDFopt](http://www.willus.com/archive/) which converts complex PDFs into Kindle friendly ones.

There are two articles published in **Freeware Genius** for you to read concerning optimising PDFs for reading on a kindle, both articles are written by the same author - Samer Kurdi

The first entitled [Optimize PDF’s for reading on your Kindle 3: crop then (optionally) convert to AZW](http://www.freewaregenius.com/optimize-pdfs-for-reading-on-your-kindle-3-crop-then-convert-to-a-kindle-friendly-format/)

The second entitled [How to read PDFs on the Kindle (or smartphone, or any small-screen device) – revisited](http://www.freewaregenius.com/how-to-read-pdfs-on-the-kindle-or-smartphone-or-any-small-screen-device-revisited/)

Comment: the question is kindle -> pdf, not pdf -> kindle

Comment: @mcalex OP wants to read pdfs on their Kindle. I didn't mention anything about converting pdf to kindle format.