# Formatting pdf for kindle

Tags: pdf, ebook, kindle, ghostscript

I started with a scan of a book which was a two-column PDF, I then used the `gs` methods outlined in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/235074/how-can-i-split-a-pdfs-pages-down-the-middle) thread to put the PDF into single page format, which worked great. This looks good on the PC screen but when I transfer the PDF to my Kindle (3rd generation) the `fit-to-screen` option chops off around 10-20% from the bottom of most pages, whereas the `actual size` option is far to big for the screen.

Is there a solution to this? should I be using different parameters than `-g4210x5950` when I do the original splitting with `gs`? or can I just resize the PDF (or its margins) I have already generated such that it is a good size for the Kindle screen? If so, what is the size I need for a 3rd gen Kindle screen.

**I want to rescale the single page pdf to correct kindle size (perhaps with `gs`), not convert. Alternatively add margins/borders so kindle fit-to-screen works without chopping ends.**

(I should say I've tried Amazon's free converter etc, but ideally I would like to keep the PDF format rather than convert, as the document is technical and the conversion doesn't seem particularly reliable. I would rather just resize the PDF/PDFmargins and keep the existing formatting if possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/385346/how-to-convert-kindle-books-into-pdf-format/513404#513404

Answer (score 3):

I have had good results with [K2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/). With the command-line options -w (width) and -h (height) you can set the output size so that it matches exactly [your Kindle's screen size.](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/screensize.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `k2pdfopt mypdf.pdf -w 560 -h 735` seems to have given similar results to the conversion services I tried (namely splitting pages across multiple pages and generally messing with the formatting). I would ideally like my pages to stay intact, just with a margin added and the main body scaled in such a way that the Kindle doesn't chop the edges.

Comment: should be achievable with `gs`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the command

```
pdfinfo -box -f 1 -l 3 mypdf.pdf
```

particularly useful in finding information about a given PDF document. For the PDF that was being chopped at bottom when put it on the Kindle, the information showed:

```
Page    1 size: 421 x 595 pts (A5)
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   421.00   595.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   421.00   595.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   421.00   595.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   421.00   595.00
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   421.00   595.00
.
.
.
```

consistent with how I created it using the command (which crops the A5 pages correctly)

```
gs \
  -o left-sections.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -g4210x5950 \
  -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" \
  -f double-page-input.pdf
```

The `-gWxH` flag is setting the size in pixels at `720dpi`.

The 3rd Gen Kindle viewable screen size is `560x735 (pixels) @ 167dpi` (according to [this](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/help/screensize.shtml) and wiki), thus at `72dpi` (standard screen) the Kindle viewable screen size translates to `(560/167)*72=241.43`  by `(735/167)*72=316.88` , so `241.43x316.88 @72dpi`. However `pdfwrite`, used below, uses a dpi of `720dpi` , at this dpi the Kindle viewable is `2414x3168 @720dpi`. Clearly `4210x5950@720dpi` is too big.

Alternatively one can see this by the fact I had created a PDF with `4210x5950 pixels @ 720dpi` and at `167dpi` this would be `976.48x1380.07`, which is clearly larger than the `560x735` of the Kindle viewable area.

Thus I need to rescale to the Kindle bounds.

One can set the device size in points directly with `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=w` and `-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=h`. At `72dpi` a `1 point= 1 pixel` (as a point is defined as `1/72` of an inch), but at `167dpi` `1 point ~ 2.31 pixels`. So if our display is `560x735 pixels @ 167dpi` then we would set `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=241 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=316` to fit the Kindle. The problem is this doesn't alter the values of `MediaBox` etc, which as shown by `pdfinfo` remain at `421x595 @72 dpi` so use the flag `-dPDFFitPage` also to ignore these, or rather rescale them to fit the device.

```
gs -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=241 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=317 -dPDFFitPage -f in.pdf
```

It seems now when `out.pdf` is viewed using `actual-size` option in Kindle it fits on the screen nicely.

I'm still not entirely clear why Kindle was chopping edges from a PDF that was too big for its screen rather than just rescaling (even if that meant very small text) in the fit-to-screen mode (I think that's what it normally does?).